# C: converting a uint8 array to a string containing the hex representation of its bytes

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a `uint8` array:

```
int i = 0;
uint8_t x[32];

for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    x[i] = i*i;
    printf("x[%d]: %02X\n", i, x[i]);
}
```

Here are the contents of the array:

```
x[0]: 0 00
x[1]: 1 01
x[2]: 4 04
...
x[14]: 196 C4
x[15]: 225 E1
...etc
```

I want to convert the `x` array to a `char` array that is equivalent to the full string representation of the byte array stored in `x`, which is:

```
00010409101924314051647990A9C4E10021446990B9E4114071A4D9104984C1
```

Basically, I want to do the programatic equivalent of

```
char hex[64] = "00010409101924314051647990A9C4E10021446990B9E4114071A4D9104984C1"
```

How can this be done in `C` programming language?

Comment: One word: `snprintf()` (`sprintf()` for C89).

Comment: When you get past `15 * 15` (where the example stopped) it is a dead duck hoping to contain the product in `uint8_t` or in 2 chars of a hex string representation. Your loop goes to `31`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` and pass `&hex[2*i]` for the printing position:

```
char hex[65];
for (int i = 0 ; i != 32 ; i++) {
    sprintf(&hex[2*i], "%02X", x[i]);
}
hex[64] = '\0';
```

Since you know that each `sprintf` will use exactly two positions, you can be sure that 32 `sprintf` calls will fill all 64 characters in `hex[64]`.

**Note:** your example tries to store 65 characters in `hex[64]`. The 65-th one is coming from null terminator of the string literal.

Comment: Thank you, my solution involved `sprintf` but I was using `hex[2*i]` instead of `&hex[2*i]`. I was wondering why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

First create a function that converts a nibble (4 bits) to a hex character, e.g.

```
char to_hex(uint8_t nibble)
{
   static const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   return hex[nibble];
}
```

Then make a sufficiently large array to hold the result (you need one extra character for the nul terminator, call the to_hex function for each 4 bits.

```
char result[65];
int i = 0;
uint8_t x[32];

for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    x[i] = i*i;
    result[i*2] = to_hex(x[i] >> 4);  //upper 4 bits
    result[i*2+1] = to_hex(x[i] & 0xf); //lower 4 bits
}
result[64] = 0; //make sure the string is nul terminated
printf("Result is : %s\n", result);
```